# Binary buffer in Python

Tags: python, binary, io, buffer

In Python you can use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) for a file-like buffer for character data. [Memory-mapped file](https://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) basically does similar thing for binary data, but it requires a file that is used as the basis. Does Python have a file object that is intended for binary data and is memory only, equivalent to Java's [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)?

The use-case I have is I want to create a ZIP file in memory, and [ZipFile](https://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) requires a file-like object.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You are probably looking for [io.BytesIO](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) class. It works exactly like StringIO except that it supports binary data:

```
from io import BytesIO
bio = BytesIO(b"some initial binary data: \x00\x01")
```

StringIO will throw TypeError:

```
from io import StringIO
sio = StringIO(b"some initial binary data: \x00\x01")
```

Answer (score 24):

As long as you don't try to put any unicode data into your `StringIO` and you are careful NOT to use `cStringIO` you should be fine.

According to the [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) documentation, as long as you keep to either unicode or 8-bits everything works as expected. Presumably, `StringIO` does something special when someone does a `f.write(u"asdf")` (which ZipFile does not do, to my knowledge). Anyway;

```
import zipfile
import StringIO

s = StringIO.StringIO()
z = zipfile.ZipFile(s, "w")
z.write("test.txt")
z.close()
f = file("x.zip", "w")
f.write(s.getvalue())
s.close()
f.close()
```

works just as expected, and there's no difference between the file in the resulting archive and the original file.

If you know of a particular case where this approach does not work, I'd be most interested to hear about it :)

Comment: It should work in most cases. I can't remember what I thought some 3 years back, but one reason would be the input to the write() method works slightly different (depending type of input) between the two versions, and I didn't want to rely on internal behavior in zipfile.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the struct package: https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html, it allows you to interpret strings as packed binary data.

Not sure if this will completely answer your question but you can use struct.unpack() to convert binary data to python objects.

```
import struct
f = open(filename, "rb")
s = f.read(8)
x, y = struct.unpack(">hl", s)
```

int this example, the ">" tells to read big-endian the "h" reads a 2-byte short, and the "l" is for a 4-byte long. you can obviously change these to whatever you need to read out of the binary data...

Comment: Do you mean to make something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239666/getting-bytes-from-unicode-string-in-python