# What is the Python equivalent of java.util.zip.Inflater?

Tags: python, zip

I have a Java program that opens a socket connection to a server that streams Zip compressed data. I read(bytebuffer) from the stream, setInput(bytebuffer) on the zip object, and inflate(outputbuffer) to get my uncompressed data.

What would be the equivalent in python?

Here is the java code:

```
byte[] compressedBytes = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = inputStream.read(compressedBytes);
zip.setInput(compressedBytes, 0, bytesRead);
zip.inflate(uncompressedBytes, 0, 1024);
```

Or, to summarize, I need a streaming inflate (not file based) zip option for python.

Comment: An interesting take, and similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116/binary-buffer-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the zlib module. java.util.zip is actually an implementation using zlib, not Zip(aka PKZIP).

Comment: Thanks! This has got me almost all the way there. Now, I'm having an issue with calling decompress in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `zlib.decompressobj()`. I think that should give you what you want. See http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html