# How to create an in-memory zip file with directories without touching the disk?

Tags: python

In a python web application, I'm packaging up some stuff in a zip-file. I want to do this completely on the fly, in memory, without touching the disk. This goes fine using ZipFile.writestr as long as I'm creating a flat directory structure, but how do I create directories inside the zip?

I'm using python2.4.

http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the filename of a file to add to 'directory/filename.ext'?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What 'theomega' said in the comment to my original post, adding a '/' in the filename does the trick. Thanks!

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from StringIO import StringIO

inMemoryOutputFile = StringIO()

zipFile = ZipFile(inMemoryOutputFile, 'w') 
zipFile.writestr('OEBPS/content.xhtml', 'hello world')
zipFile.close()

inMemoryOutputFile.seek(0)
```

Comment: Note that if you're using python 3 then you'll want to use [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html).

Comment: And if you just want to have folders without files, leave a `/` at the end.

Comment: Important is that inMemoryOutputFile is actually sent and not the zipFile object.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html). It is [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116/binary-buffer-in-python) OK to use them for zipfiles.

Comment: We do this also.  Works very nicely.

Comment: @AnotherParker If you have a more modern solution, please post and I will upvote