# Uploading a zip fileobj to S3 - KeyError: There is no item named 8388608 in the archive

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, zip

I am trying to make an in-memory zip file, which contains a bunch of JSON files. I am struggling to upload it to S3 as a file object, receiving a rather strange error. Here is my code:

```
import boto3
import zipfile
import json
import os

session = boto3.session.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'))
client = session.client('s3')

data = {'test1.json': {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
        'test2.json': {'x': 3, 'y': 4}}

zip_buffer = BytesIO()
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w')
for filename, d in data.iteritems():
    zf.writestr(filename, json.dumps(d, indent=4))

client.upload_fileobj(zf, os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET'), 'test_zip.zip')
```

This gives me:

```
KeyError: 'There is no item named 8388608 in the archive'
```

How and why is this happening? Of course there is no item `8388608` in the archive - I haven't put it there.

---

**EDIT**

If I save the file locally instead of in-memory and then re-open it, it works fine. Should I be using `tempfile` perhaps?

Comment: in-memory processing is always confusing. check this out. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610221/how-to-create-an-in-memory-zip-file-with-directories-without-touching-the-disk

Comment: @mootmoot I am already creating the in-memory zip fine, I think this may be more of a `boto3` issue.

Comment: This is not boto3 issue, you need to pass the correct file object, it is definitely not the `zf`, but the buffer object. That's why I say in-memory processing is confusing.

Comment: I found what's going on. I had already tried passing `zip_buffer`, and it worked, but it resulted in invalid zip files (Windows / 3rd party tools couldn't open them). The issues was that I was not closing `zf` before uploading them. Interesting artifact...

Comment: Well, you can post your solution, which in fact, there solution is there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue was a rather weird one. Firstly, it is the `zip_buffer` that needs to be passed, not `zf`. **But,** you need to make sure to **close the zipfile object first**, otherwise this will result in corrupted zip files that cannot be opened.

```
import boto3
import zipfile
import json
import os

session = boto3.session.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'))
client = session.client('s3')

data = {'test1.json': {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
        'test2.json': {'x': 3, 'y': 4}}

zip_buffer = BytesIO()
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w')
for filename, d in data.iteritems():
    zf.writestr(filename, json.dumps(d, indent=4))

zf.close()  # important!
zip_buffer.seek(0)

client.upload_fileobj(zip_buffer, os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET'), 'test_zip.zip')
```