# Set a Kivy Image from a bytes variable

Tags: python, image, kivy

Because of pre-processing requirements in my Kivy app I already have my images in bytes variables in my running code. The images where read from files or urls earlier in the code so i also know the file names and extensions that go with each image variable.

The Kivy `Image` class takes as input a file and reads the content in. To use this I would have to write my variables to files then read them back in. That's two unnecessary I/Os and temporary files to manage as well.

Is there a way to feed an image into Kivy from a variable? I see Kivy has a `CoreImage` class but cannot see how to turn this into a widget, and am not sure it solves my problem anyway.

```
import kivy 
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import requests
...
#read image file into bytes variable
img_from_file = open(path, "rb").read()
...
#read image url into bytes variable
img_from_url = requests.get(url).content
...
#what I think the Kivy code should look like
#this doesn't work because a path is expected
kivy_image = Image(source=img_from_file)
root.add_widget(kivy_image)
kivy_image = Image(source=img_from_url)
root.add_widget(kivy_image)
```

Comment: There may be some intermediate image api layer that happens to have a convenience function for this, but the core thing you need to do is blit your bytes to a Texture and then display that.

Comment: I investigated bliting my bytes into textures and got quite a way then hit another problem that I have raised with Kivy on Github here https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/7085.

Comment: how do I play video instead of an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works. You must supply the correct extension that goes with the image held in the bytes variable.

```
import io
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage

def get_kivy_image_from_bytes(image_bytes, file_extension):
    # Return a Kivy image set from a bytes variable
    buf = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
    cim = CoreImage(buf, ext=file_extension)
    return Image(texture=cim.texture)

# Example
url = 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2a/3b/17/2a3b175c8b6752a62a6f6915ff472f8c.jpg'
bimage = requests.get(url).content
ext = 'jpg'
image = get_kivy_image_from_bytes(bimage, ext)
# image is a Kivy Image widget
```

Comment: how do I play video instead of an image?

Comment: Don't forget to reset the BytesIO stream pointer, as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513779/706031